# ¿Cómo resolver este tipo de relación con Elocuent de Laravel?

Tags: laravel

Estoy guardando en una base de datos información acerca de encuentros de juegos, tengo una tabla llamada `teams` donde guardo los equipos para luego mostrarlos en un select.

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('teams', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Luego tengo una tabla llamada `games` donde registro los partidos

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('games', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');

        $table->unsignedBigInteger('visitor');
        $table->foreign('visitor')->references('id')->on('teams')->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->unsignedBigInteger('local');
        $table->foreign('local')->references('id')->on('teams')->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->string('local');
        $table->date('date');
        $table->string('status')->default('REGISTERED');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Mi duda es, cómo puedo relacionar ambos campos de la tabla `games`, `visitor y local` ya que en ambas se guardan el `id` del team, que requiero para luego mostrarla en la vista.

¿Se puede agregar otro campo a la relación?

```
public function team()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Team::class, 'visitor');
}
```

Yo intenté agregando "coma", y luego separados con "coma" entre corchete y no funciona `return $this->belongsTo(Team::class, 'visitor', 'local');` `return $this->belongsTo(Team::class, ['visitor', 'local']);`

En la vista lo llamo con `{{ $game->team->name }}`

Comment: Muchas gracias! Eso me funciona perfectamente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que puedes hacer, es llamar a una de las relaciones, por ejemplo, `localTeam` y a la otra `visitorTeam`, ambas se van a referir al modelo `Team`, pero cada una con su respectiva llave foránea.

```php
public function localTeam()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Team::class, 'local');
}

public function visitorTeam()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Team::class, 'visitor');
}
```

Luego podrás hacer

```php
$game = Game:find($id); 
$local_team_name = $game->localTeam->name; 
$vistor_team_name = $game->visitorTeam->name;
```

O en una vista, suponiendo que ya tienes asignada una instancia de `Game` a la variable `$game`:

```php
Equipo local: {{ $game->localTeam->name }}
Equipo visitante: {{ $game->visitorTeam->name }}
```